# Why is all of lodash ending up in my webpack build?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, redux

I've checked all the libraries that included it and they all include functions via their full path, i.e: `import find from 'lodash/find'`.

Redux is the main dependency that uses it and I checked their code too, and it correctly imports each function by its full path.

Here is the json output of my webpack build visualized:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/njjjtgtw19d52j6/Screenshot%202016-10-30%2006.27.44.png?dl=0

As you can see, lodash is taking up a huge percentage, while only a few of its methods are used. Using `webpack-bundle-size-analyzer` lodash comes out to 135kb (pre minified and gzipped of course), but it still a lot larger than it should be.

Has anyone else experienced this? I feel like it's somehow redux.

UPDATE: I found a package imports lodash functions using dot syntax: `import find from 'lodash.find'`. Perhaps that does it. What's the difference between the dot syntax and the full path syntax?

Comment: May be all the dependencies combined includes all the methods of lodash using its full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [babel-plugin-lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-lodash) to convert all imports of lodash methods like `import { map } from 'lodash';` to direct references to `import _map from 'lodash/map';`:

```
{
  "plugins": ["lodash"],
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Combine it with [lodash-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/lodash/lodash-webpack-plugin) to include just the features you need:

```
plugins: [
     new LodashModuleReplacementPlugin({ 'collections': true })
]
```